React display error code in Toast message instead of message itself
I'm having difficulty displaying error messages or a success message after making an API call. The code here is a UserRegistration call. It returns a message, "User already exists" if that's the case, or any other error.
But in this case, the toast message displays as "Request failed with status code 409", though I can see the actual message "User already exists" in the response in Developer Tools.
    export const registerUser = (payload: RegisterPayload) => async (dispatch: AppDispatch) => {
        dispatch(registerStart());
        try {
            const response = await axiosClient.post('/register', payload);
    
            let successMessage = 'Operation successful';
            if (response.data?.detail) {
                successMessage = response.data.detail
                    .map((msg: string) => {
                        const message = msg;
                        const commaIndex = message.indexOf(':');
    
                        // Check for the existence of a : and trim the message accordingly.
                        if (commaIndex !== -1) {
                            return message.substring(commaIndex + 2);
                        }
                        return message;
                    })
                    .join(', ');
            }
    
            dispatch(registerSuccess(response.data));
            dispatch(showToast({ message: successMessage, type: 'success' }));
            return { success: true, data: response.data, message: successMessage };
        } catch (error: any) {
            let errorMessage = 'An error occurred';
    
            // Check for FastAPI detail list errors
            if (error.response && Array.isArray(error.response.data?.detail)) {
                // Extract messages from detail list
                errorMessage = error.response.data.detail
                    .map((err: { msg: string }) => {
                        const errorMsg = err.msg;
                        const commaIndex = errorMsg.indexOf(', ');
    
                        // Check for the existence of comma and trim the message accordingly.
                        if (commaIndex !== -1) {
                            return errorMsg.substring(commaIndex + 2);
                        }
                        return errorMsg;
                    })
                    .join(', ');
                        } else if (error.response?.data?.error) {
                            errorMessage = error.response.data.error;
                        } else if (error.message) {
                            errorMessage = error.message;
            }
    
            dispatch(registerFailure(errorMessage));
            dispatch(showToast({ message: errorMessage, type: 'error' }));
            return { success: false, message: errorMessage };
        }
    };
    
I'm either missing something in the return of the API call or not properly catching the message in the component, can't pinpoint it though. See component code below, omitting imports for brevity
     
    const initialValues={
        firstname: '',
        lastname: '',
        username: '',
        email: '',
        password: '',
        changepassword: '',
    }
    
    const UserRegistration: React.FC = () => {
        const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
        const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState<string | null>(null);
        const [successMessage, setSuccessMessage] = useState<string | null>(null);
        const { loading } = useAppSelector((state) => state.user);
    
        const handleApiResponse = (result: { success: boolean; message?: string; data?: any }) => {
 

    if (!result.success) {
    
                const errorMessage = result.message ?? 'An unknown error occurred';
                setErrorMessage(errorMessage);
                dispatch(showToast({ message: errorMessage, type: 'error' }));
            } else {
                const successMessage = result.message ?? 'Operation successful';
                setSuccessMessage(successMessage);
                dispatch(showToast({ message: successMessage, type: 'success' }));
            }
        };
    
        const handleSubmit = async (values: typeof initialValues, { setSubmitting }: { setSubmitting: (isSubmitting: boolean) => void }) => {
            const apiValues: RegisterPayload = {
                first_name: values.firstname,
                last_name: values.lastname,
                username: values.username,
                email: values.email,
                password: values.password,
                password_confirm: values.changepassword,
            };
    
            try {
                const apiResponse = await dispatch(registerUser(apiValues));
                handleApiResponse(apiResponse);
            } catch (error: any) {
                if (error.message) handleApiResponse(error);
            } finally {
                setSubmitting(false);
            }
        };
    
        const formik = useFormik({
            initialValues,
            validationSchema: UserRegistrationSchema,
            onSubmit: handleSubmit,
        });
    

        return (

                // Form code here. Leaving it out for brevity
        )
    };
    
    export default UserRegistration;
    
    [![Toast Output][1]][1]
    
    
      [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/EDlKAmvZ.png


It would be helpful to see the response as well

can you share what's the response you're receiving when "user already exists" , try consoling the res and then extract the error/message from it, eg: response.data.error.message , something like this.

Your responses helped with pinpointing what I was getting. Turns out I was not checking for both scenarios and was also not extracting the message correctly.

I was not checking for all scenarios, was also not extracting the message(s) correctly from the response. Below is the corrected code:
    export const registerUser = (payload: RegisterPayload) => async (dispatch: AppDispatch) => {
    dispatch(registerFailure(null)); // Clear any previous error messages before starting the request
    dispatch(registerStart());
    try {
        const response = await axiosClient.post('/register', payload);

        let successMessage = 'Operation successful';

        // Access the message from the first element of the data array if it exists
        if (Array.isArray(response.data) && response.data[0]?.message) {
            successMessage = response.data[0].message;
        }

        dispatch(registerSuccess(response.data));
        dispatch(showToast({ message: successMessage, type: 'success' }));
        dispatch(registerFailure(null)); // Clear any previous error messages
        return { success: true, data: response.data, message: successMessage };

    } catch (error: any) {
        if (error.response?.data?.detail) {
            if (error.response?.status === 500) {
                const errorMessage = 'Internal Server Error. The page will refresh shortly.';
                dispatch(registerFailure(errorMessage));
                dispatch(showToast({ message: errorMessage, type: 'error' }));
                return { success: false, message: errorMessage, refresh: true };
            } else if (Array.isArray(error.response.data.detail)) {
                // Assume it's a list of field validation errors
                let errorMessage = 'An error occurred';
                errorMessage = error.response.data.detail
                    .map((err: { msg: string }) => {
                        // Assuming each error in the array has a "msg" property
                        const errorMsg = err.msg;
                        const commaIndex = errorMsg.indexOf(', ');

                        // Check for the existence of comma and trim the message accordingly.
                        if (commaIndex !== -1) {
                            return errorMsg.substring(commaIndex + 2);
                        }
                        return errorMsg;
                    })
                    .join('\n ');

                dispatch(registerFailure(errorMessage));
                dispatch(showToast({ message: errorMessage, type: 'error' }));
                return { success: false, message: errorMessage };

            } else {
                // Assume it's a single detail message
                const errorMessage = error.response.data.detail;
                dispatch(registerFailure(errorMessage));
                dispatch(showToast({ message: errorMessage, type: 'error' }));
                return { success: false, message: errorMessage };
            }
        } else {
            const errorMessage = 'An unexpected error occurred';
            dispatch(registerFailure(errorMessage));
            dispatch(showToast({ message: errorMessage, type: 'error' }));
            return { success: false, message: errorMessage };
        }
    }
};

